# Coding practice, project folder structure

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm currently making a simple manager game/simulation to learn how to handle bigger projects. 
As it is now, I have all my classes just in the /src folder created by Eclipse.

I feel that it would be a good idea to structure my project.
I have the following classes:

- Match
- TeamMatch
- Player
- PlayerFactory
- Team
- TeamFactory
- TeamSchedule
- Season

Now, one idea(and probably the right thing to do anyway!) would be to create Interface for matches, and have both Match and TeamMatch implement it. I think the logical follow up would be to have a folder named after the interface, and have the related classes inside.

But what about Player and PlayerFactory classes? Player has the basic info of a player, like age, name, etc. PlayerFactory creates Players as requested. But finding a common interface for these classes doesn't seem likely! Same with TeamFactory. Maybe have all the factory classes grouped together?

Let's look at the Team class. A team consists of players. Should these two be grouped together? A season has TeamSchedule, which has TeamMatches inside, which in turn has two teams.

This is one option I'm thinking about:

- src

  - match

    - Match
    - TeamMatch
  - factories

    - PlayerFactory
    - TeamFactory
  - league

    - Season
    - Player
    - Team
    - TeamSchedule

Any suggestions, blatant mistakes I've made or completely different views on the subject?

Comment: put your package names in lowerCase, referring to `Math` and `Factories`'folders'

Comment: fixed the package names as suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest:

create a base package which should have a name like `org.managergame`.

create three packages under the base package named `team`, `match`, `player`.

`Match` and `TeamMatch` go to the package `match`.

`Player` and `PlayerFactory` go to the package `player`.

`Team`, `TeamFactory` and `TeamSchedule` go to the package `team`.

Everything else can be under the base package.

Comment: +1: group classes in pacakges by problem domain, not by what pattern they implement or other technical similarities

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205 might be helpful to understand the differences between -Package By Feature- and -Package By Layer-.

Comment: it looks like _package by feature_ is what i want here. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to check out [Package Naming Conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Answer (score 2):

I usually have packages by layer: `model`, `service`, `persistence`, `util`.